# Ruby program to distribute books among kids equally

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop

Imagine I have 5 different books, `books = ['a','b','c','d','e']`, and I want it to share it among 3 children `kids = [k1,k2,k3]`. I use zip and cycle function to do this operation, say

```
books.zip(kids.cycle)
```

so that output will be

```
{"a"=>"k1", "b"=>"k2", "c"=>"k3", "d"=>"k1", "e"=>"k2"}
```

next day, I have another 4 books, `books = ['f','g','h','i']`, this time Iwant to distribute these books among same 3 kids equally end of second day, ie. all 3 kids should have 3 books each at the end of the second day.

How to achive this?

Comment: How indeed? I suspect that's the homework-to figure it out.

Comment: Could you make clearer what your input, output and interim (between days) data structures are? It is quite important what information you have starting second day, since otherwise `(books1 + books2).zip( kids.cycle )` looks like it would do the job. There has to be some information retained between days though, otherwise it is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to think about structures which you are going to use for storing input and output data as well as some intermediary data if needed.

With hashes and arrays you can achieve arbitrarily complex structure.
However it is very often profitable for future to encapsulate data within classes using OOP paradigm.

With hashes and arrays it could look like this:

```
#init data with your input
kids = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Kate']
books_over_days = [
  [ 'book1', 'book2', 'book3'],
  [ 'book4', 'book5']
]

#init data for storing your output
kids_to_books = {}
kids.each {|kid| kids_to_books[kid] = []}

books_over_days.each do |books|
  kids.each {|kid| kids_to_books[kid] << books.sample}    
end 

puts kids_to_books.inspect
```

You could use some encapsulation and classes to write it differently + some books generator so data is dynamically generated instead of declaring it statically. It could look like this

```
class Kid
  attr_reader :books, :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @books = []
  end

  def add_book(book)
    @books << book
  end
end

Book = Struct.new(:name)

class BooksGenerator
  attr_reader :books
 def initialize(factor)
    @books = []
    @factor = factor
  end

  def generate
    0.upto(Random.rand(@factor)) {|e| @books << "book#{Random.rand(@factor*@factor)}"}
    @books.uniq!
  end
end

days_n = 3

generator = BooksGenerator.new(5)
kids = [Kid.new("Alice"), Kid.new("Bob"), Kid.new("Kate")]
days_n.times do
  generator.generate
  kids.each { |k| k.add_book(generator.books.sample)}
end

puts kids.inspect
```

Without more details it is hard to say something more.

Comment: i appreciate it, am new to ruby thats y i depend on built in functions, not writing complete logic on my own, so i followed first method u suggested, in this case, one book will be shared by 2 kids. One kid should have a book, that is shared with another kid.

Comment: -> end of first day 5 books distributed to 3 kids, so 2 kids will be having 2 books and one kid having only one book. These kids will start reading these books, so these books cannot be given to another kid the next day. 
    
-> second day books should be distributed to kids in such a way that k1 should get 1 more book i.e 'f', similarly k2 should have 'g' and k3 should have 'h' and 'i'. Is this possible?

Comment: is there a way i can contact u,like by mail?

Comment: @shashi - try to modify above code. You'll never learn if you don't start coding by your own. If one book cannot be assigned to more than one kid then instead of getting a sample from the array _Array.sample_ and leaving array unchanged you could just pop data from the array so it is not available for another kid. However, if you need equal distribution of books then it is better to iterate through books in the first place and in each iteration assign a book to a kid, which in fact can be done in one line as amerdidit suggested in his answer. It all depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store your output in a variable, you could do `kids.rotate!` until the kids array starts with the next kid that's supposed to recieve a book.

After that, you can do the same zip action again.

```
books = ['f','g','h','i']
books.zip(kids.cycle)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate

Answer (score 0):

If `books = ['a','b','c','d','e']` and `kids = [k1,k2,k3]` and then `books2 = ['f','g','h','i']`

you could do the following

```
(books + books2).zip(kids.cycle)
```

the results will be the following:

```
=> [["a", "marc"], ["b", "frank"], ["c", "melisa"], ["d", "marc"], ["e", "frank"], ["f", "melisa"], ["g", "marc"], ["h", "frank"], ["i", "melisa"]]
```

Comment: end of first day 5 books distributed to 3 kids, so 2 kids will be having 2 books and one kid having only one book. These kids will start reading these books, so these books cannot be given to another kid the next day. I want all 3 kids to restore their old books, no sharing, in this case how to proceed further?

Comment: second day books should be distributed to kids in such a way that k1 should get 1 more book i.e 'f', similarly k2 should have 'g' and k3 should have 'h' and 'i'. Is this possible?